# Insert one time but 2 record on database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

My database is MySQL and I use PHP as my language. I wrote a function and I run my update or insert query with this function. This function is working for all of my queries and it seems ok.

At moment for one of my Tables when I insert a value I got record on my database!! I checked my function and it runs only for one time (in beginning of my function I used `echo $myquery` and it wrote my query for one time) but in my database I got 2 records.

Do you have any idea about this problem?

```
Field---Type---Attributes---Null  

eventsID---int(10)---UNSIGNED---NO
auserID---int(10)---UNSIGNED---No
bUserID---int(10)---UNSIGNED---No
type---smallint(5)---UNSIGNED---No
amount---int(10)---UNSIGNED---No
cType---tinyint(3)--- ---No
cAmount---int(10) ---UNSIGNED---No
dateTime---timestamp---ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP---No---CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: we can't help you unless you put your PHP code here. Edit your question and paste the relevant PHP code.

Comment: JohnPs right, does your script do any redirects then the function gets called twice?

Answer (score 1):

the reason is pretty obvious. 
your script being executed twice per request.

most of time it occurs from lame implementation of SEO urls using mod_rewrite as a 404 handler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is not running twice via 2 calls?

Echoing you're query will only only echo it once - but it could be called twice.

Perhaps try logging something as far down as you can? (At execution level?)